# javascript argument not passing through a function

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get a user's current city plus whatever argument that's being passed through getCity function when clicked but i'm getting undefined for 'x' variable. here's the code..

```
<button onclick="getCity('burger')">burger</button>
<button onclick="getCity('steak')">steak</button>
<button onclick="getCity('taco')">taco</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
//get city
function getCity(x) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPos);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
//get lat and long
function showPos(position) {    
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    //get address
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng 
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //get city
    if (results[0]) {
        var city = results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name;
        var x = x;
        alert(x +" "+ city); // i'm getting undefined + currentcity
    }
}
});
}
</script>
```

i'm getting undefined + currentcity. how do i make it so i get burger + currentcity if i click on burger button?

Comment: Your `x` in `getCity(x)` is a string. How would that `x.innerHTML` possibly be working?

Comment: Your `x` is a local variable and is not shared across the two functions

Comment: i see.. i thought showPos function was inside getCity function bc when i call getCity().. showPos() gets executed too. Any suggestion how i can get this working? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your script to work you have to declare a global variable

```
<button onclick="getCity('burger')">burger</button>
<button onclick="getCity('steak')">steak</button>
<button onclick="getCity('taco')">taco</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var food;
//get city
function getCity(x) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        food = x;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPos);
    } else { 
        //x.innerHTML does not work because x is a string not an element
        this.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
//get lat and long
function showPos(position) {    
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    //get address
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng 
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //get city
    if (results[0]) {
        var city = results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name;
        var x = food;
        alert(x +" "+ city);
    }
}
});
}
</script>
```

Another possible solution would be passing it to pass the `x` to the `showPos` function.

```
<button onclick="getCity('burger')">burger</button>
<button onclick="getCity('steak')">steak</button>
<button onclick="getCity('taco')">taco</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
//get city
function getCity(x) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            showPos(position, x); 
        });
    } else { 
        //x.innerHTML does not work because x is a string not an element
        this.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
//get lat and long
function showPos(position, x) {    
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    //get address
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng 
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //get city
    if (results[0]) {
        var city = results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name;
        //var x = food;     x is already a parameter of this function so don't declare it again
        alert(x +" "+ city);
    }
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Both solutions should work fine unless you have overseen some codes. Please update the latest code that you have currently

Answer (score 1):

You second last statement

```
var x = x;
```

asssigns an undefined x to x. Both "x"s are undefined.

Comment: i was assuming x is coming from getCity(x) and the onclick function getCity('argument');?

Comment: the function showPos is not in the scope of getCity, so it does not know the existence of 'x' :)